# Set DNN LogIn Module Horizontal

Tags: c#, vb.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I'm working with DNN (DotNetNuke) and I have to change the default login module. This module it's vertical by default, by don't know how to set it horizontal. Already tryied to find the sources of this module but all I found were some Local Resources Files and some VB files.

Any idea????

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it by myself, just had to modify:

admin/Authentication/Login.ascx
DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/DNN/Login.ascx

[Take a look at this link](http://www.mylifebbs.com/2009/06/dotnetnuke-customizing-your-login-part-3/)